# Saving variable for later use and validation

Tags: python, python-3.x, variables

I need the variable, idnum, to be callable from multiple functions (let the user enter the number and the program retrieves it when needed). I tried the code below but comes up with the error message:

```
TypeError: unorderable types: function() > int()
```

What needs changing to allow the code to work and validate the input.

```
idnum= ""

def idnum():
    idnum = int(input("Enter the id number of who you want to edit: "))
    edit()


def again():
    edit()

def edit_info():
        print()
        print()
        print ("Select what you want to edit")
        edit_menu()

def edit():
    num_lines = sum(1 for line in open('Surname'))
    print()
    if idnum > num_lines or idnum ==0 or idnum < 0:
        print("Not valid")
        time.sleep(0.5)
        print("Try again")
        time.sleep(0.2)
        again()
    else:
        print()
        for file in ["Forename", "Surname", "Email", "Date of birth", "Home address", "Home phone number", "Gender", "Tutor group"]:
            with open(file) as f:
                print(f.readlines()[idnum-1], end='')
```

idnum()

Comment: You cannot have a function and variable with the same name.  You're assigning `idnum` as a string variable then defining a function called `idnum`.  Later when `idnum` is being used the code references the `idnum` function, not the string variable, which is the direct cause of your error.

Answer (score 0):

Try `global idnum = idnum = int(input("Enter the id number of who you want to edit: "))`

Answer (score 0):

you should not practice to have same function name and variable name in your code.
To run this code update your program to pass idnum as argument with **edit()** function.

```
def idnum():
    idnum = int(input("Enter the id number of who you want to edit: "))
    edit(idnum)

def edit(idnum):
    num_lines = sum(1 for line in open('Surname'))
    print()
    if idnum > num_lines or idnum ==0 or idnum < 0:
    <Rest Code>
```